# Running Two Versions of Java JDK

Tags: java, java-6, jdeveloper, jdk1.4

I primarily use JDeveloper 10 with JDK 1.4.2 on Vista. I would like to install Eclipse and have it run the latest JDK 6.

Is this possible without conflict?

Ideally I would like to just use JDeveloper and switch back/forth between JDK versions. Is this possible?

Answer (score 6):

It is indeed possible, you can have as many JDKs in system as you wish.
Just install them into different directories, then you can add a new JDK to your IDE (they support having multiple).

You can choose one on per-project basis.

Comment: Indeed - I have all the latest updates of Java 2, 3, 4, 5 and 6 installed, and a codebase that compiles each package to differing JDK versions (e.g. my GUI programs target Java 6, but others might target Java 3, while all core library packages target Java 2).

Comment: Nitpick: You cannot really add JDKs to Eclipse, only JREs (which a JDK always includes). Eclipse will use these only for running your programs. Compilation always uses Eclipse's internal compiler (whose settings can be configured under Prefs/Java/Compiler).

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure with JDeveloper 10, but in eclipse you can specify which installed JDK you wish you use under window>preferences>Java>Installed JREs.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the JRE for Eclipse to run under with the `-vm` command line switch or in eclipse.ini. e.g. `-vm "%JAVA_HOME%/bin/javaw.exe"`

You can specify the JRE for executed code via the Window:Preferences:Java:Installed JREs menu.

Answer (score -1):

If you select project properties in Eclipse, then Java Build Path, you can choose a different JDK to use when building the project.

Comment: -1 This is very misleading. First, ou don't need a JRE when building, you need a JDK. And secondly, to change the build that Eclipse performs, you must change settings under Preferences/Java/Compiler.

Comment: At any rate, usually you just want to *run* with a different JDK/JRE version. That is configured in the "Run/Debug" dialog.